# Detect changes of components in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular2-changedetection

I'm working in a component and i need to detect if there's any change inside the component, or if has been changes in the variables... The thing is that based on that, i will do something... Is it possible?

For example, this is my code:

```
 public var1: boolean;

 public var2: string
```

and this is my HTML

```
<component-boolean [(ngModel)]="var1"></component-boolean>
<component-string[(ngModel)]="var2"></component-string>
```

So i need to detect inside of my component, that there's have been changes based on the value of all the variables.

Of course, i need it to be dynamic and not to have to declare the change detection for every variable becouse i won't know the amount of variables.

Answer (score 1):

You want two-way-binding with `@Input` and `@Output`. With `@Input` data flows to the child, whereas `@Output` emits events to parent.

We can create a two-way-binding combining these two, where `@Output` variable has the same name as the `@Input` variable + the suffix `Change` (important!)

So mark your child tags with:

```
<component-boolean [(bool)]="var1"></component-boolean>
<component-string [(str)]="var2"></component-string>
```

and in your `component-boolean`:

```
@Input() bool: boolean;
@Output() boolChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

and when you make changes to this value, just emit that change and parent will catch it!

```
this.bool = true;
this.boolChange.emit(this.bool)
```

Implement this in the similar manner for your other component.

If you do not want the two-way-binding, you can have a different name for the `@Output` and trigger event:

```
@Output() boolHasChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

this.boolHasChanged.emit(this.bool)
```

Child tag:

```
<component-boolean [bool]="var1" 
                   (boolHasChanged)="boolHasChanged($event)">
</component-boolean>
```

and parent TS:

```
boolHasChanged(bool: boolean) {
  console.log(bool)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Output an event if something changes inside your component:

```
@Output() booleanChanges: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```

If something changes just emit an event like that:

```
this.booleanChanges.next(whatever);
```

And then you can change your HTML like that:

```
<component-boolean [booleanChanges]="var1"></component-boolean>
```